# How to transfer a folder with the files name and size to excel?

Tags: excel-2007

Is it possible to transfer to excel the exact name of the files and its size from a folder, without having coding knowledge?

Comment: Decent enough question, but belongs on super-user.

Answer (score 0):

With no coding, you could run `dir /C *.xls > a.txt`, then import `a.txt` into Excel.